# PostgreSQL results of conditional insert

Tags: postgresql

I've got a simple query which inserts data to table when value (unique) does not exist:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE hash = 'somelonghash'
    )
    THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable (id, hash, status, datecreated)
        VALUES (123, 'somelonghash', 2, '2018-01-01T12:34:56.789Z');
    END IF;
END $$;
```

But if I want to receive results like "RETURNING *" if there was an insert, I receive error: "**query has no destination for result data**".
I've tried something like:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE hash = 'somelonghash'
    )
    THEN
        INSERT INTO mytable (id, hash, status, datecreated)
        VALUES (123, 'somelonghash', 2, '2018-01-01T12:34:56.789Z')
        RETURNING *;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

or even like

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE hash = 'somelonghash'
    )
    THEN
        WITH ins_res AS (
            INSERT INTO mytable (id, hash, status, datecreated)
            VALUES (123, 'somelonghash', 2, '2018-01-01T12:34:56.789Z')
            RETURNING *;
        ) SELECT * FROM ins_res;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

I assume I'm missing SELECT statement somewhere at the very beginning, like SELECT * FROM (IF-THEN-ELSE results), but can't figure out where. Also this query without IF-THEN works:

```
WITH ins_res AS (
    INSERT INTO mytable (id, hash, status, datecreated)
    VALUES (123, 'somelonghash', 2, '2018-01-01T12:34:56.789Z')
    RETURNING *
) SELECT * FROM ins_res;
```

Comment: Why don't you using `insert ... on conflict do nothing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `insert ... select`:

```
    INSERT INTO mytable (id, hash, status, datecreated)
    SELECT 123, 'somelonghash', 2, '2018-01-01T12:34:56.789Z'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE hash = 'somelonghash')
    RETURNING *;
```

But: is there a reason preventing you from using `on conflict` instead?

Comment: The reason is that every ON CONFLICT attempt adds id and if this operation goes every 1 minute ids numbers are becoming enormous.
Oh, wait. Looks like it works